# How to use input from the user

Tags: python-3.x

Probably very basic problem but don't know how to approach it.   I only started learning Python.
On my course I was asked to prepare name generator.

1)Program must ask for a number - how many names.
2)Then ask to enter names number of times indicated above.
3)Then those names must be printed with small modification.

My idea is to start with :

```
while True:
try:
    user_input = iter = int(input("How many names?\n"))
except ValueError:
    print("\nOnly whole numbers allowed. Please try again.")
```

Then ask user to input X number of names (number from previous question):
I can't figure the code to ask X times plus change the number in the end e.g.

"Enter name number" 1
"Enter name number" 2
...

I know how to put them in the list after but I stuck on the previous step.
Would be anyone so kind to help me with it?
Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

Not entirely sure what you need but the solution sound like this:

```
name_list = []

for i in range(0, user_input):
    new_name = input('\n')
    name_list.append(new_name)

print('all names given)
```

Is that what you are searching?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
n=int(input("Enter the number of students: "))
for i in range(1,n+1):
    b=input(f"Enter name number {i} : ")
```

Your output will be as follows:
it may help you.

```
Enter the number of students: 4
Enter name number 1 : vp
Enter name number 2 : xyz
Enter name number 3 : abc
Enter name number 4 : pqr
```

you can append the input values in a list then you can print values however you want.